# How to find a bounding rectangle around diagonal line on map ? (Geo-Locations)

Tags: c#, geolocation, geometry, gis, geo

A user draws a line on a map and wants to find some information in a specific distance of that line.
I have **A** and **B** locations in **"lat, lon"** format and the user tells me the distance ***(the distance between A and A1)*** in **"meter, kilometer,..."**.
How can i calculate **A1, A2, B1, B2** locations in **"lat, lon"** format? I'm using C# and [CoordinateSharp](https://coordinatesharp.com) for working with locations.

[image]

p.s: I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807203/determine-a-bounding-rectangle-around-a-diagonal-line) and it works on cartesian grid system but i couldn't adapt its code for my problem.

Comment: Why couldn't you adapt it? Because you need an exact solution for spherical geometry or because you could not convert the lat, lon to numbers in km?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes almost both of them, i can tolerate maximum 10 meters of error in my calculations and i don't know how to replace lat for Y and long for X, longitude numbers are different for each latitude, now somehow i think this formula might not work for geo locations :-?

Comment: If you need an exact solution then this is probably rather a question for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Convert lat/lon to UTM (CoordinateSharp can already to this apparently), perform the calculations in UTM (it's using meters as units) and then convert back to lat/lon.

Answer (score 2):

Having `A` and `B` coordinates, you can calculate bearing in both points (note bearings are distinct in general case).

With bearing `Fi` in point `A` you can calculate bearings `Fi - 90` and `Fi + 90`, and find points A1 and A2 at needed distance at corresponding bearings.

The same for B1, B2

You can get formulas from **Bearing** and **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** chapters at [this page](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Bearing

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )

where   φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point 
(Δλ is the difference in longitude)
```

Destination

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing 
(clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; 
d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius
```