# How to calculate coordinates perpendicular to a line between two latitude / longitude coordinates?

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude

### Given

- Line defined by two coordinates (**latitude / longitude** in decimal degrees) `A` and `B`
- Offset / distance to the line in **meters** `d`

### Wanted

- Coordinates `A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2` ("below" and "above") perpendicular to the line at a distance `d` for point `A` and `B`

[image]

### What I have tried already

In a cartesian coordinate system, the calculation can be done easily, e.g. following [How do you find a point at a given perpendicular distance from a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133897/how-do-you-find-a-point-at-a-given-perpendicular-distance-from-a-line) given `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` and `N` being the distance:

```
dx = x1-x2
dy = y1-y2
dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
dx /= dist
dy /= dist
x3 = x1 + (N/2)*dy
y3 = y1 - (N/2)*dx
x4 = x1 - (N/2)*dy
y4 = y1 + (N/2)*dx
```

### What I have achieved

I have tried the above solution on pen & paper with coordinates like `A (5/3)` and `B (10/4)`, the results were fine, the calculated points were on a perpendicular line.

Then, I have tried it with "real coordinates" (e.g. `lat=52.50004577636719`, `lon=13.39927864074707`) and I treated those coordinates as if they were normal 2D cartesian coordinates. The output is distorted -> the points are *not* on the perpendicular line.

[image]

### Questions

- When I assume that my coordinates are "cartesian" coordinates, then I get distorted results, e.g. when rendering those coordinates it appears to be not really perpendicular. Can I somehow get rid of this distortion?
- Is "perpendicular to a line between two coordinates" defined at all when dealing with latitude / longitude values?
- Is there a way to use the "cartesian method" and then map back to real latitude / longitude?

[EDIT] Solved by calculating the bearing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550894/844416
https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/

Comment: [Look  at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550894/844416)

Comment: Thank you! That guided me in the right direction.